# Celery-Django weblogs Grok Pattern

Tags: django, celery, logstash-grok, filebeat, grok

I'm trying to get the grok pattern for the following web log line:

```
[2020-12-14 10:44:57,598: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task celery.chord_unlock[1f93d444-835f-4ff4-b730-915b0f17f9ab] retry: Retry in 1s
```

and this is the pattern I've got:

```
%{DATESTAMP:timestamp},%{INT:pid}:\s%{DATA:loglevel}%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

which simulates this:

```
{

  "timestamp": [
    "20-12-14 10:44:57"
  ],

  "pid": [
    "598"
  ],

  "loglevel": [
    ""
  ],

  "message": [
    "INFO / ForkPoolWorker-1] Task celery.chord_unlock [1f93d444-835f-4ff4-b730-915b0f17f9ab] retry: Retry in 1s"
  ]

}
```

Comment: and? where are your efforts?

Comment: Sorry I'm new at this... I didn't know how to paste the simulated attempts

Comment: np, fixed that for you

Comment: you can thank me by accepting the answer/upvoting :)

Comment: sure thing! doing that right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is a better one for you:

```
%{DATESTAMP:timestamp},%{INT:pid}: %{DATA:loglevel}/%{DATA:worker}] %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

build it using [grok debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) and [cheat-sheet](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns).